# what's the most efficient way in c++ to break a bool array into an int array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function where the input and output are bool arrays (longer than the simple example).
Internally the function works on fixed length integers (i.e. integers that are exactly 12 bits or
7 bits, ...). So the first step is to convert the input bool array into an equivalent int array.
Here's an example :

```
 bool bits[10*12];
 unsigned int ints[10];

 for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
  {
   x=1;
   t=0;
   for(int b=0;b<12;b++)
   {
    t+=x*bits[k*12+b];
    x*=2;
   }
   ints[k]=t;
 }
```

which converts an input array of 120 bits to an int array with 10 entries, each being 12 bits.
This works fine but I'd like to see if there are more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: The speed of light is a fundamental limit of our shared universe. It cannot be exceeded without violating the laws of physics. Similarly, if one has an array of 120 values that must be checked, nothing can be done other than checking each one of those 120 values, without violating the same laws of physics. Even if some micro-optimizations are possible here, modern multi-Ghz CPUs will make the result of any micro-optimization mostly academic.

Comment: 10 ints, even on 16 bit platforms, have 160 bits, plenty of room for 120 `bool`s, @DrewDormann

Comment: you can definitely replace multiplication by shifts, also move calculation of k*12 out of the loop

Comment: `t+=x*bits[k*12+b];` will become something like `t |= bits[k*12+b] ? (1<<b) : 0;`

Comment: When you *profile* your (supposedly) more efficient way, make sure you enable the optimizer to compare the performance of the given implementation against the performance of the (supposedly) better implementation.  In compilers these days, the optimizer is surprisingly good.

Comment: Each int is at least 16 bits.  It might be more.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: You also might want to consider using `std::bitset` instead of rolling your own.  It's hard to be completely sure if it's what you need given that we don't know the reason why you're doing this.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: *integers that are exactly 12 bits* --  Are you attempting to write an LZW compressor/decompressor?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not exactly that but the math is very similar...

Comment: As a stylistic thing, I’d suggest breaking out a function that takes a span of up to 12 `bool`s and returns an `int` packed the way you want. Then your main loop can repeatedly call that. It should wind up a zero-overhead abstraction but makes loops like these easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at every single bit at least once. There is no way around it. So the most efficient way is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of bits.

Your algorithm is `O(n)`. Congratulations.

The only way to be more efficient is to not need a conversion at all. Why don't all your code work with 12bit ints?

Or did you maybe want more performant code instead of more efficient?

Comment: The internal code uses the 12 bit integers to access look up tables...so skipping the conversion is probably not an option.

Comment: What distinction are you implying between "performant" and "efficient"? IMHO they're equivalent. Efficiency is more than just Big-O complexity, coefficients matters for real-world solutions.

Comment: Efficiency is about the theoretical resource usage (e.g. memory or time) of an algorithm for an input `n`, especially how it changes as `n` changes. So it's very much about Big-O notation. On the other hand performance is about the practical side. When you benchmark something you measure the performance. How long does it actually take for a specific input? Coefficients matter for the performance, not the efficiency. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I should have been more explicit...I want the code to run as fast as possible

Comment: Have you profiled your code? is the conversion even a problem? Why do you need an array of bool instead of e.g. vector<bool> or bitset? 120 bit fit in 2 uint64_t and your conversion can just be a view into those. The most speedup you can get is by not doing things.